# Microsoft Excel: Copy values across rows into one column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Given a spreadsheet laid out something like this:

```
     A       B         C       D       E
    ---     ---       ---     ---     ---
  1 user1   1/1/18    1/1/17  1/1/16
  2 user2                     1/1/16  1/1/15
  3 user3             1/1/17
  4 user4                             1/1/15
  5 user5   12/31/18          9/8/16
```

How can I scan each row left to right and copy the FIRST column value detected after column B *into* column B so that the result is this:

```
     A       B         C       D       E
    ---     ---       ---     ---     ---
  1 user1   1/1/18    1/1/17  1/1/16
  2 user2   1/1/16            1/1/16  1/1/15
  3 user3   1/1/17    1/1/17
  4 user4   1/1/15                    1/1/15
  5 user5   12/31/18          9/8/16
```

If there's already a value in column B, it needs to remain intact. All other values in column B would be the result of the scan of each row as described above. My macro skills are lacking these days, so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could work:

```
Sub MyCombine()
    With Sheet1
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 2)) Then
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 2).End(xlToRight).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```